# Minimising noise from servers

Tags: ubuntu

I have 5 tower servers (Lenovo system x3500 m5) and they can get a bit noisy in the office.  I think it might be the fan for the power unit or cpu. We don't have access to the server room.

What solutions are there?

Comment: If they are in the server room, and you can hear it from the office... your walls are too thin. Earplugs might be a sensible suggestion if you can't insulate the walls somehow.

Answer (score 4):

You have a two choices:

1. Put them in the server room.
2. Purchase quieter servers.

These machines are **servers**. They're meant to be put away in a proper server room, where no one cares how much noise they make. Regarding #2 above: sure, there *may* be quieter servers than what you currently have, however, any proper server is going to make a *lot* more noise than a typical desktop machine.

Seriously, sort out what needs to be done to put them in the server room. Everyone (including the servers) will be happier after this happens.